# Hebrew words and letters become question marks

Tags: php

I'm trying to recieve information from text file, and however when it's in hebrew, it shows "????" instead of the hebrew word

I can't change the file encoding, because ZaraRadio Outputs it, so I tried to set the charset of file to UTF-8, this way:

```
$npf = "CurrentSong.txt";
$ans = file_get_contents($npf);
$ans = mb_convert_encoding($ans, "UTF-8", "auto");
```

but it still not working...

any suggestions?
thanks.

Comment: And .txt file encoding is?

Comment: @nevermind i don't think i know, and there is no way to check this out (I didn't found one yet. i assume its unicode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely `auto` will not serve because the file is encoded in a single byte encoding. You don't say which encoding it uses, but [ISO-8859-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-8) is probably it.

```
$ans = mb_convert_encoding($ans, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-8");
```